# WooCommercer/WP - Add custom field output to admin-new-order email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Having an issue related to creating a new custom dropdown menu on my checkout page in woocommerce. I was able to build the custom field using code I found here and there, but I can't get it to actually send me the result (what the user has chosen) via my email template.

Here's the code I added to my function.php in order to create the new field. It's a dropdown menu with 3 choices, user HAVE to select one.

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('Méthode de Paiement').'</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Faites votre choix de paiement'),
        'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
    'options'     => array(
        'choice1' => __('Cash - Montant exact', 'woocommerce' ),
        'choice2' => __('Cash - Montant inexact', 'woocommerce' ),
        'choice3' => __('Carte', 'woocommerce' )
        )
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['my_field_name'])
         $woocommerce->add_error( __('Ce champ est obligatoire, veuillez choisir.') );
}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));
}
```

Now this is the code in the admin-new-order.php, which is the email template that the admin of the woocommerce site gets when a new order is sent.

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin new order email
 *
 * @author WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
 * @version 2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php echo admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->id . '&action=edit' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ) ); ?>)</h2>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #eee;" border="1" bordercolor="#eee">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( false, true ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, true, false ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

All I want to do is add one line to that email, pretty much anywhere, that says something like "the output for the custom field is choiceX", which would tell me which one of the 3 the user has selected.

I can't seem to find the variable or the code I have to use to make this work.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try reviewing my tutorial on [customizing WooCommerce checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/?p=517) which includes a section on adding the data to emails. The easiest is to just add your data to the array of order meta that WooCommerce will display:

```
function kia_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['some_field'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Some field' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ),
            );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'kia_email_order_meta_keys', 10, 3 );
```

Or you can customize the output however you'd like by adding something to one of the available hooks in the email template (anything that says `do_action()` is a hook):

```
function kia_display_email_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $some_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true ),
    $another_field = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_another_field', true ),
    if( $plain_text ){
        echo 'The value for some field is ' . $some_field . ' while the value of another field is ' . $another_field;
    } else {
        echo '<p>The value for <strong>some field</strong> is ' . $some_field. ' while the value of <strong>another field</strong> is ' . $another_field;</p>;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'kia_display_email_order_meta', 30, 3 );
```