# Add a new field to woocommerce_email_customer_details or any other part of emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Ok so I am building a woocommerce site for a client and they love it but the only issue is they need a customer number to come through with the email for all new orders. They are willing to go in and fill in this info for each user, but I cannot find out how to get this info to automatically send with the new order email.

I am using WP - Members plugin to add custom information to the users profile, and have created a field there called Customer # (option name: customer_number) I cannot figure how to get woocommerce to add this number to the email that is sent when they place the order (to the admin)

I have tried many different things, it seems like it should just be a hook but I dont know how to get the values or have not been able to figure this out yet in any way.

I have looked and looked and this is my last resort, my minimal understanding of php and hooks is probably my downfall here, so please be very clear if instructing me in that way.

I will not give up on this issue, so I hope someone can help!

Comment: If you have tried many different things pleas share them, so we know what you have tried and did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737455/woocommercer-wp-add-custom-field-output-to-admin-new-order-email

Comment: well ive tried every kind of hook i can find, but i dont know anything about them, so i dont think im doing any of it right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can adapt from my [tutorial on customizing the checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) to display some extra info in the email:

```
function kia_display_email_order_user_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $user_id = $order->customer_user;
    if( ! empty( $user_id ) && ( $data = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_some_user_meta', true ) ) != '' ){
        if( $plain_text ){
            echo 'The user data for some field is ' . $data;
        } else {
            echo '<p>The user data for <strong>some field</strong> is ' . $data . '</p>';
        }
    }    
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'kia_display_email_order_user_meta', 30, 3 );
```

In this case we'll replace the `get_post_meta()` of my tutorial with `get_user_meta()`.... and knowing that the user Id is stored in the `$order->customer_id` property of the `$order` object.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I have added this code to the functions.php of my child theme, but I am still not getting any new outputs in the email, do I need to change any values in this (the field I am trying to get outputted into the email is set through the back end by the admin not through the form itself and has a value of customer_number)

Comment: Well the `get_user_meta( $user_id, '_some_user_meta', true )` line is an "example" line and the key `_some_user_meta` needs to be changed to match your data. Perhaps `customer_number` assuming that the Members plugin is saving user meta normally.

Comment: Ok ive tried this, im not getting any new output in the emails tho, im sorry for my ignorance in this department, I am new to working with hooks and even php.

Comment: function kia_display_email_order_user_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $user_id = $order->customer_user;
    if( ! empty( $user_id ) && ( $data = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_customer_number', true ) ) != '' ){
        if( $plain_text ){
            echo 'The user data for some field is ' . $data;
        } else {
            echo '<p>The user data for <strong>some field</strong> is ' . $data . '</p>';
        }
    }    
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'kia_display_email_order_user_meta', 30, 3 );

am i missing anything?

Comment: I GOT IT! Thank you so much! I had to remove the first _. Thank you so much for your help with this!